# Dynamically update google maps with received longitudes and latitudes

Tags: java, php, html, google-maps

I've written a java applet which sends longitudes and latitudes trough POST requests. I need to write a server page which will receive this data and dynamically shows a google map with the received points on it.  (php/etc...)

I don't know how to start with this, because I really don't know what to do first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/ has all the information you need.

So you simply need to get a server page to recieve your POST data, parse the longitude and latitude and then get the image result from the URL below (look inside the src attribute).

Should be fairly obvious what all the parameters are, zoom level on google maps and the size of the map in pixels. Alternatively if you just want this map displaying on a webbrowser you just output the `img` tag shown below

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
```

[image: Generated Map]

EDIT:
The URL will dynamically generate the map each time you send a POST request. If you need the data to continuously change then maybe using POST requests isnt the best way to do it. POST is best used for data which you want to send off to a server then do something with (generate a single map etc).

As an example...
The user wants a map of where a particular street is that they have clicked on
>
Send POST request
>
Get the map using the Google Maps URL and send this back/output to a webpage.

As an alternative you might want to look at the various Maps APIs on the site. A better link for this would be https://developers.google.com/maps/

It's not quite clear what you are aiming to do so providing an example usage would help with a better answer.

Comment: But the problem is that the map has to be dynamically. So the map should change after it has been created already. How can I do this?